# Error when trying to execute Sass script via Zsh terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: command-line, sass, zsh

I've recently switched over from using the Bash command prompt to Zsh on Mac OSX.

Problem I have using Zsh is that the command I would use to watch Sass files no longer works.

The script file I have is `sass.sh` and the content is...

```
#!/bin/sh
sass --style expanded --watch Assets/Styles/Sass:Assets/Styles --debug-info
exit 0
```

...but every time I run `sh sass.sh` I get the error...

```
/Users/<home-directory>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find sass (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/<home-directory>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users/<home-directory>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1230:in `gem'
from /Users/<home-directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/sass:18:in `<main>'
from /Users/<home-directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/<home-directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

...and I don't know how to resolve this problem.

It looks like it just can't locate the Sass gem, but if I run `gem list --local` I can see `sass (3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.1.20, 3.1.17, 3.1.15)` in the list of gems. BUT I do also get an error again displayed first...

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/<home-directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rubygems-bundler-0.2.8/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- rubygems_bundler/rubygems_bundler_installer (LoadError)
```

I've looked around on Google and SO and found miscellaneous references to similar issues but none that helped me and my specific issue.

Can any one tell me what I need to do to resolve this issue so I can continue to use Zsh and run my Sass script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems the answer is very simple. When using Zsh you no longer use the `sh` command but the `zsh` command.

So instead of `sh sass.sh` I just needed to do `zsh sass.sh`